# run javascript only once

Tags: javascript, cookies

I need to run javascript only once, save to cookies, then, when try to execute function, check  if cookies saved, if so, don't trigger function.

I'm sure this script has an error because it doesn't do what I need :

```
var prom = getCookie('prom');
if (prom === null || prom === '0') 
{
if (document.getElementById('tst')){
    var str=document.getElementById("tst").innerHTML;
    var n=str.replace("Login","Logout");
    document.getElementById("tst").innerHTML=n;
    setCookie("prom",'1',1);
}
}
```

Html code where script triggers to change 'Login' in 'Logout'

```
<a href="login"  title="log in" class="login_button" id="tst">Login</a></span>
```

Cookies script :

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    if (exdays) exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays) ? '; expires=' + exdate.toUTCString() : '');
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(name) {
    var re = new RegExp(name + "=([^;,]+)");
    var value = re.exec(document.cookie);
    return (value !== null) ? unescape(value[1]) : null;
}
```

Jsfiddle test if http://jsfiddle.net/8yZaP/11/

Comment: `getCookie()` saves to a global variable?

Answer (score 6):

Change

```
if (prom = '0'){
```

To

```
if (prom === '0'){
```

(Of course, assuming `getCookie` and `setCookie` persist similar to [sessionStorage](http://code.google.com/p/sessionstorage/)).

Comment: You should always use identity operators (`===`), not comparison operators (`==`) in javascript. [Related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/javascript-vs-does-it-matter-which-equal-operator-i-use)

Comment: @jbabey, +1 good point -- thanks

Comment: Strange, now it doesn't trigger the function. On console error: ReferenceError: "prom is not defined"    if(prom === '0'){

Comment: From your edit, you need to assign the return value of `getCookie()` to something: eg `var prom = getCookie('prom');`

Comment: I made the modifications. No more errors on console but script still did't trigger. Also On Resources-Cookies- no event for 'prom'. If I remove if (prom === '0') function is executed.

Comment: Please check this Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8yZaP/11/ , if you remove if (prom === '0') script/cookies work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JBFFn/8/ seems to work.